# Get all details from serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

So I have my family serializer like below

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=Parishioner.objects.all(),
        allow_null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address', 'monthly_contribution', 'members', 'enabled')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        depth = 1
```

Family can have multiple Parishioners so it's One to Many relationship.
When I send a GET request to `/api/family/1/` I get below response

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mendis Family test",
    "address": "No 48, Katukurunda, Moratuwa",
    "monthly_contribution": 50.0,
    "members": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ],
    "enabled": true
}
```

as you can see in members array I can see only id of the members.

How can I get all data of `member` within that array (NOT just the id. name, address, etc..) ?

I tried changing `depth = 1` to many numbers but it did NOT do the trick.

I already have searializer to `member` its called `ParishionerSerializer`

but I should be able to add `members` to `Family`

Comment: Do you have a serializer for `Member` ?

Comment: @JPG yes. its called ParishionerSerializer

Comment: You can use that serializer as @Hafnernuss mentioned in his answer

Comment: @JPG I'm getting error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own Serializer for `Member`:

```py
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.TextField(...)

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('id', 'name', )
```

and use it in your Family Serializer:

```py
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address', 'monthly_contribution', 'members', 'enabled')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Update based on the comments:

The nested serializer is of course not writeable by default, this is described more in-depth in the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). By passing `read_only=True` to the serializer, it is possible to use it for `GET` requests. If you want to change the nested fields, you will need to override the `update()` method of your outer (!) serializer, or use something like [django writeable nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested).

Comment: I'm getting error 
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Comment: I have updated the answer, remove the queryset argument.

Comment: If you for some reason have to pass a queryset, pass it as the first argument:
= MemberSerializer(Parishioner.objects.all(), many=True)

Comment: Then I'm getting this error --> The `.update()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.

Comment: For this you will need your own custom update() method, read up here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

But this an entire question on its own.